Passing Java List <String> to XSLT
Im having an issue with XSLT 2.0 using java to return a list of multiple string values.  Here is my approach
xmlns:fn="java:myFunction" //java function returning List<String>

<xsl:variable name="returnList" as="xsd:string*" select="fn:myFunction('inparam')" />
<element<xsl:value-of select="$returnList[1]"/></element> //This has 1 of the expected values
<element<xsl:value-of select="$returnList[2]"/></element> //This is empty but shouldnt be


Which XSLT 2 processor do you use, tell us the exact version and edition. Also explain which extension function approach you use for your Java function, whether that is a reflexion or some other API (e.g. Saxon has both https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation12/extensibility/extension-functions-J/reflexive-functions/index.html as well as https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation12/extensibility/extension-functions-J/ext-full-J.html)

Saxon EE 9.7.  and I believe its using the reflexive extension. I was however able to make this work and, unfortunately it was an issue in the java.  sorry for the bother, just took me a while to catch it
